# Jira and GitLab webhook! How to integrate?

Tags: jira, git-commit

How can i integrate Jira and Gitlab and status will change on request!

```
Git commit -> ED-1511 #AutomationState Running

Jira ticket (ED-1511) - >> will change AutomationState on Running
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do this with the out of the box functionality of Jira and Gitlab.

From the structure of your commit message it looks like you are trying to use the [smart commits](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-smart-commits-298979931.html) functionality in Jira. Smart commits only allow you to perform three actions:

1. Log time
2. Comment on an issue
3. Transition an issue to a new workflow state

This is not something you can do with smart commits. In addition the current [Jira Gitlab integration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/jira.html) doesn't seem to support smart commits.

If you wanted to build this functionality you could probably build something yourself that:

1. Listens for [Gitlab webhooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html)
2. On receipt of a Gitlab webhook calls the [Jira REST api](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/?utm_source=%2Fcloud%2Fjira%2Fplatform%2Frest%2F&utm_medium=302#api-api-3-issue-issueIdOrKey-put) to modify the issue

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the GitLab integration with JIRA described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/jira.html) should do what you want. I only recently set this up with our JIRA cloud instance and GitLab running in an AWS instance, and I haven't tried to integrate transitioning JIRA tickets from Git commit messages. However, the documentation seems to indicate that it is possible.